# find all header tags and check each tag has id attribute and if not add id attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to find all header tags from the content and check each tag has id attribute and if not, then add id attribute using jquery

Below is my code:

```
var headings = $("#edited_content").find("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6");
    $.each(headings, function (i, heading) {
        attributes = heading.attributes
        $.each(attributes, function (j, value) {
            if (value.name == 'id') {
                alert("id present");
            } else {
                alert("id absent");
                $(this).attr('id', i);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a simple

```
var headings = $("#edited_content").find("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6");
headings.attr('id', function(i, id){
    return id || 'prefix-' + i
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZxD74/)

If you want you can fine tune it using a not() filter like `headings.not('[id]').attr(...)`

Comment: using a number for an id isn't quite valid in most browsers.

Comment: @gdoron in html5 it is valid.... but in css it wouldn't work.... any way we can easily add a prefix to the id

Comment: +1, you're right about HTML5, was I wrote, "most browsers" are not HTML 5 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   if ($(this).attr("id"))) {
         alert("id present");
    } else {
        alert("id absent");
        $(this).attr('id', i);
    }
```